# Adds same ID to the arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a problem when trying adding new books to the Arraylist
If I have a list like :

```
  DVDJNSHRR00001,GSTSMCSCF00002, STPHNKART00003, DVRDNRHRR00004, JKRWLNSCF00005, BRHMSLSCF00006, BZDRCFCRI00008, BZDRCFCRI00009
```

and if I add 
new books in my test class
by

```
    b1.addBook("ART","Dr Julius Erving");
    b1.addBook("ART","Vytenis Matijosaitis");
    b1.addBook("ART","Fedor Dostojewski");
```

I get the output of:

```
     DVDJNSHRR00001, GSTSMCSCF00002, STPHNKART00003, DVRDNRHRR00004, JKRWLNSCF00005, BRHMSLSCF00006, DRJLSRART00007, BZDRCFCRI00008, BZDRCFCRI00009, VTNSMTART00009, FDRDSTART00010
```

Instead of:

```
     DVDJNSHRR00001, GSTSMCSCF00002, STPHNKART00003, DVRDNRHRR00004, JKRWLNSCF00005, BRHMSLSCF00006, DRJLSRART00007, BZDRCFCRI00008, BZDRCFCRI00009, VTNSMTART00010, FDRDSTART00011
```

The program itself is quite long (500) lines so I will post only the part where I think is my mistake.
My part of code which deals with it looks like:

```
        if(this.existingNumberIDs.contains(this.idPart)){

                while(findID==true){
                    findID=false;
                    nextBookID++;
                    this.idPart = String.format("%05d", nextBookID);
                    if(!this.existingNumberIDs.contains(this.idPart)) {
                        findID=true;
                    }
                    findID=false;
                }
            }
        String charPart = authorID + this.genre;

        this.bookID = charPart + this.idPart;


        setBookID(this.bookID);
```

At the time before adding those 3 books `nextBookID=6`, so basically my code works fine with `b1.addBook("ART","Dr Julius Erving")` but only increases the ID for `b1.addBook("ART","Vytenis Matijosaitis")` to `9` when it should increase it to `10` because `00008` and `00009` already exists and `b1.addBook("ART","Fedor Dostojewski")` should increase to `11`. Can any of you see why that part of code is wrong?

Comment: It is always hitting the `findID = false;` at the end of your while loop You may want to put an `else{ findID = false;}` or it will always be false and it won't go through the loop again. or remove that last `findID=false;` in that while loop should work as well.

Comment: Sorry, but still not working as it should. Same output

Comment: Maybe try taking out the '!' in your if statement. If I am reading that right.

Comment: OMG!!! It is working

Comment: @Augustas Please delete your Question, or provide and accept an Answer so this matter is marked as closed.